# rails using dirty method for tracing purposes using mobility gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobility

A rails controller method is attempting to pass object changes

```
      if @union.update(union_params)
puts '||'
puts @union.changed
puts @union.changes
        @union.update_with_log(union_params, current_user.id)
```

However, when this runs the console registers an empty hash for the changes and does not even handle the `changed` verb.

```
||
{}
```

The `changes` verb acts [as expected](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)when testing in the console with a variable invoked.  However, the application's operating context is with tranlsatable variables with handling through the `mobility` gem.

In practice the console registers edits the following manner:

```
Mobility::Backends::ActiveRecord::KeyValue::TextTranslation Update (0.4ms)  UPDATE "mobility_text_translations" SET "value" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "mobility_text_translations"."id" = $3 [...]
```

Why is this behaviour different with `mobility` & an instance variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that needs to be invoked is `previous_changes` as [indicated in the documentation](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility#dirty-tracking) towards the end of the Dirty tracking section and not `changes` (the documentation is not explicit on the latter point at time of writing).